# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VMware and Virtual Box ova/ovf images

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, ubuntu-14.04, ovf

I have a Java application that I'd like to distribute as a virtual machine appliance image (ovf or ova) for VMware and VirtualBox using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The image would include the operating system itself, required OS packages, my Java application, all pre-configured and ready-to-run when powered on.

What's the best way to create OVF and OVA files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have been working with VirtualBox some and do not feel expert, but here is what I would do.

- Download the 14.04 LTS iso image from Ubuntu [14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).
- Build a VM in VirtualBox using the New button. This will be the template for your Appliance.
- Give it a catchy name like "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64amd for Java App".  Type should be "Linux" and Version should be "Ubuntu (64 bit) or (32 bit) as appropriate.
- Set the amount of RAM necessary.
- Click the Create a virtual hard drive now button. Click the Create button.  I believe that VMDK Type will help with portability. Select dynamically allocated (makes a smaller ova file), especially if you intend to distribute the ova files. Give the disk image a name and the size that you desire, I think 10GB would be minimum. Click the Create button.
- Next select your VM and Click Settings to get the settings window.
- Select Storage and then select the Icon for the CD/DVD disk.  On the right, click the CD-ROM icon and locate the Ubuntu 14.04 amd 64 iso file that you downloaded.  Click okay.
- Then click the start button from the main window .

The VM should boot to the ISO DVD image that is in the virtual CD/DVD drive.  Respond to all of the prompts.  Save the username and password for later.

When the build is done and Ubuntu boots to the virtual harddrive, then apply all new updates: (you  will need your password created earlier)

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- Then after the reboot, use the "Devices" menu  at the top of the VirtualBox window for your VM to "Insert Guest Additions CD Image ..." to install the extras that makes the Ubuntu image work better in the VirtualBox environment.
- Now install all of the Java extras and your applications. I can't say much here.
- Lastly, using the File > Export Appliances  menu option, select your VM from the list and Click Next.  I usually accept the format OVF 1.0 and Click Next. Fill in the settings information with links to your support web page if available. I have seen people put the username / password information in the description field for distribution.  Then Click Export.

You should have a new OVA VirtualBox Appliance.

Comment: In the latest virtualbox versions you can directly start up the newly created vm and an installation wizard will prompt you to add the ISO (no need to edit storage) and get updates.

When I did this (for xenial 64bit), I found it loaded the O/S and updates fine, but failed to fully restart (error:  base address). After I did a power down (I tried the close/save state option first - not sure that made any difference) it was fine to start up again.
After the restart, add the guest additions etc, and ACPI shutdown - then it is easy to export the vm to an ova via the machine menu.

Comment: I meant the file menu, not machine menu, sorry.